# Eigenvalues of an induced diffeomorphism on cohomology groups

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Let a map $f:S \rightarrow S$ be a diffeomorphism on a closed surface S.

When the map is induced on 2nd (de Rham) cohomology group
$$
f^{*}:\text{H}_{DR}^{2}(S) \rightarrow \text{H}_{DR}^{2}(S),
$$
where $\text{H}_{DR}^{2}(S)\cong \mathbb{R}$, does the map $f$ have an eigenvalue of 1?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: If the map preserves the orientation, yes. If not, no.

Comment: $f^*$ is a map between one-dimensional vector spaces, it has eigenvalue $1$ if and only if it is the identity map. Can you find a closed surface $S$ and a diffeomorphism $f : S \to S$ such that $f^*$ is not the identity map?

Comment: @MoisheCohen Because the map is a diffeomorphism, it is a bijection(i.e. 1-1) map. So, the map sends a homology class in $\text{H}_{2}(S)$ to itself and it means that the map has an eigenvalue of 1 on the homology group. Therefore i thought that the dual map $f^{*}$ has the same eigenvalue. Am i right?

Comment: No you are not right. What automorphisms of the group of integers do you know?

Comment: @MoisheCohen $\phi_{1}(n)=n$ and $\phi_{2}(n)=-n$.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Did you mean that an eigenvalue of the map depends on whether the map preserves the orientation or not?

Comment: @JunhyeongKim: Yes, that's the idea. Also, you should consider cohomology with integer coefficients.